# Why does React Native Stack Navigation not persist keyboard?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, keyboard, react-navigation

When I navigate back first time, keyboard persists, but if i abort back navigation and then do it, keyboard does not persist anymore. What's causing this weird behavior? Can I fix it? I can't even understand why keyboard persists in the first case, let alone why it doesn't in second.

[image: 1]

Here's minimal reproducible example:

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Foo: undefined;
  Bar: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function Bar() {
  return <TextInput inputMode="tel" autoFocus />;
}

function Foo({
  navigation,
}: {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;
}) {
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener("transitionEnd", () => inputRef.current?.focus()),
    [navigation]
  );

  const onChangeInput = (text: string) => {
    setInput(text);
    if (text.length == 1) navigation.navigate("Bar");
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={inputRef}
      value={input}
      onChangeText={onChangeInput}
      inputMode="tel"
      autoFocus
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Foo" component={Foo} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Bar" component={Bar} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is React Navigation.

You have autoFocus set to true on your TextInput on both screens. So the input will auto focus each time the screen renders, at least for the first time. The focus state will persist when you navigate back to the screen.

However, your problem may be coming from not unsubscribing from the navigation listener to clean up after each re-render because according to the docs when autoFocus is set to true, the input will focus with componentDidMount or useEffect. When you slide back but cancel, the input is likely un-focusing but you can't see it because Bar is on top of Foo. The screen doesn't necessarily 'unmount' when you go the next one- state persists.

in your useEffect, make this change.

```
  useEffect(
   const listener = navigation.addListener( "transitionEnd", () => inputRef.current?.focus() );
   return listener
    [navigation]
  );
```